# Pandas - Traverse Table to Get Accumulated Days and Activity Count

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get like the gap days, accumulated days, and total non-sale activities prior closing a sale.

Greatly appreciate any help as I couldn't think of a clean way doing this. I tried using pandas' shift but I couldn't get the proper results.

***EDITED to include some other scenarios:***

**Input pandas table:**

| ID | Date | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID123 | 2021-01-01 | Activity Type 1 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-05 | Activity Type 2 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-07 | Activity Type 1 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-10 | Sales |
| ID123 | 2021-02-01 | Activity Type 2 |
| ID123 | 2021-02-15 | Sales |
| ID456 | 2021-01-01 | Sales |
| ID456 | 2021-01-05 | Sales |
| ID789 | 2021-01-20 | Activity Type 1 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-25 | Sales |
| ID789 | 2021-01-27 | Activity Type 2 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-30 | Sales |

**Desired Output:**

| ID | Date | Activity | Gap from Last Activity | Accumulated Days | Activity Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID123 | 2021-01-01 | Activity Type 1 |  |  | 1 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-05 | Activity Type 2 | 5 | 5 | 2 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-07 | Activity Type 1 | 2 | 7 | 3 |
| ID123 | 2021-01-10 | Sales | 3 | 10 | 3 |
| ID123 | 2021-02-01 | Activity Type 2 |  |  |  |
| ID123 | 2021-02-15 | Sales | 15 | 15 | 1 |
| ID456 | 2021-01-01 | Sales |  |  | 0 |
| ID456 | 2021-01-05 | Sales |  |  | 0 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-20 | Activity Type 1 |  |  | 1 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-25 | Sales | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-27 | Activity Type 2 |  |  | 1 |
| ID789 | 2021-01-30 | Sales | 3 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` operations:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
m = df['Activity'].str.startswith('Activity')
g = df.groupby(['ID', (~m[::-1]).cumsum()])

df2 = df.assign(**{'Gap': g['Date'].diff(),
                   'Accumulated': lambda d: d.groupby('ID')['Gap']
                                             .apply(lambda x: x.fillna('0').cumsum()
                                                               .mask(x.isna())
                                                   ),
                   'Count': lambda d: g.cumcount().mask(d['Gap'].isna()).ffill(limit=1)
                   })
```

output:

```
      ID       Date         Activity    Gap Accumulated  Count
0  ID123 2021-01-01  Activity Type 1    NaT         NaT    NaN
1  ID123 2021-01-05  Activity Type 2 4 days      4 days    1.0
2  ID123 2021-01-07  Activity Type 1 2 days      6 days    2.0
3  ID123 2021-01-10            Sales 3 days      9 days    3.0
4  ID456 2021-01-01            Sales    NaT         NaT    3.0
5  ID456 2021-01-05            Sales    NaT         NaT    NaN
6  ID789 2021-01-20  Activity Type 1    NaT         NaT    NaN
7  ID789 2021-01-25            Sales 5 days      5 days    1.0
8  ID789 2021-01-27  Activity Type 2    NaT         NaT    1.0
9  ID789 2021-01-30            Sales 3 days      8 days    1.0
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick help. What does the m = df['Activity'].str.startswith('Activity') do? Is it possible if values of Activity is like 'Call', 'Meeting', etc.?

Comment: Then use a list of activities instead: `df['Activity'].isin(['Call', 'Meeting'])`. Or a blacklist: `(~df['Activity'].isin(['Sales']))`

Comment: Thanks so much! Work for me now. Just added a clean-up to clear the Count that carries over to the first record of the next ID